# My JFrame doesn't display properly on Java1.5_u22/Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, java-5

I don't understand what is wrong. It looks like a bug in JVM 1.5/Linux/x86

My JFrame is ok on JVM 1.8, but on 1.5, it is empty and it doesn't display content pane. And the frame is not maximized unless it is under 1.8

```
public class FrameBuilder {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static JFrame getFrame() {
        frame.setTitle(Labels.get("app.title"));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        frame.addWindowListener(getWindowListener());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);//should display orange background
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        return frame;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 1.5? 1.6 and 1.7 (and 1.8) are available on Linux in both Oracle JDK/JRE and OpenJDK/JRE. 1.6 is where things really started to "stabilize" -- I wouldn't recommend trying to support 1.5 unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: try calling `final JFrame frame = getFrame(); frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Swing & AWT GUIs should be started on the EDT..  (Don't claim a bug in the JVM while the code is doing things known to cause 'unpredictable effects'.)

Comment: Thank you SnakeDoc, it solves my problem. I develop under 1.5 because my application will be deployed on many desktop, including old ones.

Comment: You do realize that Java 1.5 hasn't been supported since [**April 2008**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html), right?

Comment: I also realize that many people don't update java on their desktop. And I don't want to force people to update java to run my application.

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I don't agree. Initialization of the GUI should be done in the main thread. Only changes of the GUI should be done in the EDT.